# Python IRC Bot, distinguish from channel messages and private messages

Tags: python, networking, bots, irc, channel

I'm coding a simple IRC bot in Python. Actually, It can connect to a specific channel, read messages and send response, but it can't distinguish between channel messages and private messages.

**Example**:
John, connected to the same channel, send a private message to the Bot's chat, like "!say hello";
Bot have to send "hello" to the same private chat, only to John.
Instead, when bot read "!say hello" in channel's board, have to send "hello" to the channel.

**My code:**

```
ircmsg = connection.ircsock.recv(2048)
ircmsg_clean = ircmsg.strip(str.encode('\n\r'))
if ircmsg.find(str.encode("!say")) != -1:
    try:
        parts = ircmsg_clean.split()
        content = parts[4]
        connection.sendMsg(channel, content)
    except IndexError:
        connection.sendMsg(channel, "Invalid syntax")
```

**Connection file:**

```
def sendmsg(channel, msg):
ircsock.send(str.encode("PRIVMSG " + channel +" :" + msg + "\n"))
```

I know how to send a message to a specific user:

```
def sendPrivateMsg(username, msg):
ircsock.send(str.encode("PRIVMSG " + username + " :" + msg + "\n"))
```

But have to know from where the message came, channel or user, and send appropriate response.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the message is included in the protocol message, now you are just not using it.

In the part where you do this

```
parts = ircmsg_clean.split()
```

you get it in to the list `parts`.

If I remember correctly, and understand the RFQ right, the irc message you receive from the server looks something like this:

> :John!something@something.org PRIVMSG BotName :Are you receiving this message ?

so splitting that would result in this:

```
[':John!something@something.org', 'PRIVMSG', 'BotName', ':Are', 'you', 'receiving', 'this', 'message', '?']
```

The sender of the message is that the first element `parts`, so `parts[0]`. You would need to strip away the extra ':'.

The target of the message is at `parts[2]`, and that can be your name or the channel name, and you then need to compare the target to your own name to know if it is a message to you or to a channel.

If that is true, you can then do something like this:

```
source = parts[0].strip(':')
content = ' '.join(parts[3:]).strip(':')
connection.sendMsg(source, content)
```

Notice that the actual content of the message is also splitted, so you need to rejoin that into a string if you are doing it like that. If you are hitting that `IndexError` it means that you received a message that had only one word, since the first word is at index 3, not 4.